# whats the difference between Cargo and SMW?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, semantic-mediawiki

The page on the [mediawiki extension "Cargo"](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Cargo/de) states that it is similar to SMW and stores template content / data in databases. Besides the technical and UI parts - what is the difference to SMW?

I am looking at SMW because of the notion of "properties" as "typed" hyperlinks in a graph of "categorized" wiki-pages.

Is this functionality provided by Cargo as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an alternative comparison between SMW and Cargo, including some recommendations, at https://professional.wiki/en/articles/managing-data-in-mediawiki

Answer (score 2):

A comparison between Cargo, SMW and Wikibase can be found here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Managing_data_in_MediaWiki